# Real Case Attack on AI model

Tags: ai-security

There are so many papers showing the vulnerability of some AI/ML models. I read some of them only demonstrate their attack to a model "in the lab".

Are those attacks really feasible in real-case scenarios? Are there any real reported cases when AI/ML models in production got attacked or fooled?

---

*"Attack" here sounds very general, but yes, I am curious about any general case when AI/Model in production gets attacked or fooled by any method (adversarial, backdoor, etc.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found one that I think is the closest one: Tesla hacked to drive on the wrong lane with stickers.

- news: https://www.businessinsider.com/tesla-hackers-steer-into-oncoming-traffic-with-stickers-on-the-road-2019-4
- paper: https://www.usenix.org/conference/usenixsecurity21/presentation/jing